# Close a specific Form and showing another Form on the Same Event in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I have 2 Forms.

```
Form1: Containing a Button
Form2: Contains a label
```

I want on button click event the Form1 closes and immediately Form2 appears

My code for Form1 is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
     Form2 obj = new Form2();
     obj.Show();
     this.Close();            
}
```

Here the Problem is when i click the button, the Form2 appears for some miliseconds and get closed with Form1.
i Want to overcome the problem by just closing the Form1.

Help...

Comment: Not sure if this will resolve your issue, but have you tried to `Show` `Form2` in the `Form_Closing` Event of `Form1` instead of the `button_click` event?

Comment: Not yet ....
i`ll try

Comment: nw i tried ur idea but again its closing bcoz of code this.close in button_click event

Comment: I think today m not going to hv d solution of my problem   :|

Comment: I tried this.hide(); Form1 obj=new Form1(); obj.ShowDialog(); this.close();

Comment: this code worked !! :)

Comment: It sounds like this could be due to the `Dispose`.  When `Close` is used on a `Show` it does the `Dispose`, but when `Close` is used on a `ShowDialog` the `Dispose` is not automatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `Form1` is closing is because your Program.cs is creating and showing `Form1`. When you close the form, your program thinks it's done and shuts down.

Two options:

1. Instead of calling `Form1.Close();`, set `Form1.Visible = false;` This will hide the form but not end its existence.
2. Instead of having your Program.cs directly run `Form1`, create an entrypoint class that has a reference to `Form1` and `Form2` and run an instance of that in your `Main` method. In that class you can handle `Form1.Closing` and create your `Form2`. But then you need to know when your program is really done and manually exit it.

Comment: in ur point 2. i dnt knw hw to create an entrypoint class n where to create it ..